# Spring Integration DSL - How to create an XPath Splitter?

Tags: xpath, spring-integration, dsl, splitter

How do you create an XPath Splitter using Spring Integration DSL?  What is the DSL equivalent of this:

```
<!-- Split the order into items creating a new message for each item node -->
<int-xml:xpath-splitter id="orderItemSplitter"
                   input-channel="orderChannel"
                   output-channel="orderItemsChannel">
    <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="/order/items"/>
</int-xml:xpath-splitter>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Integration Java DSL doesn't have any `<xpath-splitter>` specific component because it is enough easy to configure via regular Java configuration:

```
@Bean
public AbstractMessageSplitter xpathSplitter() {
    return new XPathMessageSplitter("/order/items"); 
}

...

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow xpathFlow() {
return IntegrationFlows.from("inputChannel")
            .split(xpathSplitter())
            .get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Artem.  That is indeed easy enough, presuming one is aware of the existence of the XPathMessageSplitter.  What I'm finding is that where factories exist, like Transformers, Pollers, MessageChannels, Amqp, Jms, Files, Ftp, Mail, etc., the DSL is as easy to use as the XML.  But where no factories are available to help, I tend to get stuck looking for the right way to do something.

Comment: Yeah. I understand your concern , but that is still not clear for us why people don't take a look into Framework classes. For this purpose we recently added some not in the Reference Manual: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips. From other hand it looks like something like Splitters factory would be good in DSL as well. Feel free to raise a GH issue on the matter and we'll address it soon.

Comment: "why people don't take a look into Framework classes" - To make it clear, one must understand that framework users see the framework completely differently from framework authors.  Time is limited, there are thousands of classes, the XML is fully documented and easy to follow, and was made to be easy to consume - it is so easy to add a namespace to  an XML doc and see the available elements.  With the JC DSL, some parts are easy, and others are very abstract.  Your addition to the doc will help some.  I'll open a GH on Splitters, and thanks for all your hard work - its appreciated.